# variable 'MySet::group' is uninitialized. always initialize a member variable (type.6)

Tags: c++

i have a problem:

variable 'MySet::group' is uninitialized. always initialize a member variable (type.6)

i dont understand what is the mistake, it seems to me that the variable is intizialize.

this the Source file

```
 MySet::MySet()
{   
    int* group = NULL;
}
```

this is Header File

```
class MySet
{
private:
    int* group;
    int size;

 public:
    MySet();                          //defult- creating an empty group
```

Comment: in the hader file  right ?

Answer (score 1):

`MySet::group` (the class member) is not initialized. In constructor you initialize a *local* variable, which dies as soon as this constructor finishes.

Change it to

```
MySet::MySet()
{   
    group = NULL;
}
```

Or better, using [member initializer list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor)

```
MySet::MySet() : group {NULL}
{   
}
```

Comment: it still dont initialize


MySet::MySet()
{ 
 group = { NULL };
}

Comment: @NikaTatikishvili Can you explain something more? The second snippet should definitely fix this warning. The first snippet - it depends on the code analyzer. Technically it doesn't *initialize* the variable. It is first uninitialized and then assigned. And `size` is also uninitialized, you may get a warning from that too.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is declaring and initializing a local variable that happens to have the same name as the member.

There are two possible ways to initialize a member variable.

The traditional way is to use the constructor's initializer list:

```
MySet::MySet() : group(nullptr) 
{
}
```

A more modern method (since C++11) is to provide an initializer in the member's declaration instead:

```
class MySet
{
    // ...
    int* group = nullptr;
    // ...
};
```

If you write this:

```
MySet::MySet() 
{
    group = nullptr;
}
```

it's not an initialization but an assignment.